# How can one transform a compound sentence into a direct question?

Tags: questions, compound-sentences

I have a compound sentence:

> It's bad, and we should not do it.

How can transform it into direct question? Should I invert the word order in both parts of the sentence or only in the first one?

Comment: *Is it bad, and should we not do it?* - is this what you are asking?

Comment: it depends on the intention behind the question. You might assume it's bad and ask whether it should be done, or you could ask whether it's bad, etc. You might even ask a question to which you want the quote to be the answer. There isn't a 1:1 mapping between statements and questions in this context.

Comment: Should we do it, it being so bad?

Comment: @Lawrence I want to ask something like: "Is it true that it is bad, and we should not do it?", but without "Is it true" construction.

Comment: If it's bad, we should not do it? Or -- If it's bad, should we not do it?

Comment: @Madruel Thinking about this some more: the quote isn't a simple conjunction; it has an implicit *so* - "It's bad, and **so** we should not do it." Turning the first part into a question is easy: "Is it bad?" Turning the second part into a question depends on its rationale: perhaps some other value that trumps naive good/bad - "Is it bad, *but* should we do it *anyway*?" Or it might be rhetorical - "Is it bad, and should we *then* not do it?"

Comment: @Lawrence, thanks, looks like rephrasing it to complex sentence is the best way to go. But I still wonder if I can keep the original structure, creating a [Compound question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barreled_question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Davo's version

> Is it bad, and should we not do it?

is grammatically fine, and a direct inversion that *can* mean pretty much what you want it to mean. It sounds odd, though, because negative interrogatives like ***should we not?*** (and also the contracted form ***shouldn't we?***) are idiomatically used for *affirmative* statements, roughly translated something like

> I think we probably should, and want you to say whether you agree.

This usage is so ingrained that I have a hard time "translating" without using another negative-positive; other interpretations would be:

> *I think we should, don't you agree?*

or

> *Don't you think we should?*

The compound question at the top is unlikely to be interpreted this way, because of the first clause, but it still just doesn't sound quite idiomatic.

To get around this, we need to rephrase the second part of the question in a more unambiguous form, or restructure the question altogether. The first possibility would be to simply remove the negation:

> Is it [good or] bad, and should we do it?

Notice that this question does not presuppose an answer, so we possible answers would include:

> Original statement:
>
> - It is bad, and we should not do it.
>
> Opposite of original:
>
> - It is good/not so bad, and we should do it.
>
> Something in between:
>
> - It is bad, but we should do it [anyway].
> - It is good, but we should not do it [anyway]

Alternatively, we could leave the order of the words in the second part so that we aren't making it into a negative interrogative. This also requires changing the way that the two parts of the sentence are connected:

> Is it **so** bad **that** we should not do it?
> or
> Is it bad, and **therefore** we should not do it?

These versions come close to the meaning asked for in comments, *is it true that it is bad and we should not do it?* However, in the original compound sentence any causal relationship between the two clauses is only implied, and in these versions it is made explicit.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can. Let us, for the sake of argument, come up with a more concrete sentence:

> It is a lame idea, and we should not even be discussing it in public.

The only way to turn this into a double-barreled question (which, by the way, is a logical fallacy ... just saying ...) is to toss in some extra words (and drop the "and"):

> Is it [such] a lame idea [that] we should not even be discussing it in public?